# Does $f(\epsilon)=o(\epsilon\ln(\epsilon))$ imply $\frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=o(1)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I have the following homework question:

> Does $f(\epsilon)=o(\epsilon\ln(\epsilon))$ imply
>   $\frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=o(1)$ ?

It doesn't seem correct to me, using the definition I could only get
$$\frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=o(\ln(\epsilon))$$ and it doesn't seem
that if $g(\epsilon)=o(\ln(\epsilon))$ then $g(\epsilon)=o(1)$.

To contradict this I wish to find a function $c(\epsilon)$ s.t $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}c(\epsilon)=0$$
but $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}|c(\epsilon)\ln(\epsilon)|>0$$

I am having difficulty finding such a function, I tried a few and
checked them using WA, they all satisfied $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}c(\epsilon)=0$$
but they all also satisfied that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}|c(\epsilon)\ln(\epsilon)|=0$$

Can someone please help me find such $c(\epsilon)$ ? (or surprise
me and show that this statement is in fact true)

Comment: @Glinka To edit "epsilon" into "varepsilon" in a 3 years old question is petty at best. Please spend your energy on worthier causes.

Comment: @Censi LI Why did you approve this edit?

Comment: @William Why did you approve this edit?

Comment: @Did, because it looks better this way. What motivates you to reverse it manually is far more interesting question

Comment: @Glinka Who says so ("looks better this way")? The OP?

Comment: @Did, I say this. In my opinion it looks better. The question of something "looking better" in general is subjective. At my understanding \epsilon is shorter to type and it saves time, but \varepsilon is better percepted. So whenever I see the first way of writing the letter, I correct to the second one. You're saying I shouldn't?

Comment: @Glinka Rhetorical question if ever there was one (or cannot you read my first comment?).

Comment: @Did, don't understand your hostility... Or why you went through trouble of correcting it back. You don't explain your action at all. But whatever, the matter is paltry and I'll trust you know better. I'll keep in mind not to make such edits again.

Comment: @Glinka Perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation
$$f(x)=_a o(g(x))$$
means $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\iff \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=_a o(1) $$
and to contradict your implication just take $f(\epsilon)=\epsilon$

Comment: Isn't $f=o(1)$ ?

Comment: @Belgi Yes, it is. But $f(\epsilon)/\epsilon=1$ is not.

Comment: My mistake, for a moment I forgot I need to divide $f$ by $\epsilon$. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Belgi In my counterexample $f=o(1)$ but $\frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\neq o(1)$

Comment: @Belgi You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful what you wish for -- setting $c(x)=\frac{42}{\ln x}$ satisfies your conditions, but doesn't help much with the original question... or does it? :-)

Comment: Acually, I planned on taking $f=\epsilon\ln(\epsilon)\cdot c(\epsilon$. So this gives us Sami's answer, which turns to be a valid counterexample. But it seems you think your answer is not useful to the original question..why ?

Comment: I originally misread the lower-case $o(1)$ as upper-case $O(1)$ in which case you wouldn't get a contradiction (since $42=O(1)$).